# AngularJS + Jasmine Unit Test: How to make an angular.constant visible inside the angular.forEach()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to make an angular.constant visible inside the angular.forEach()?

In the below sample, angular.constant is accessible in the parent and child describe blocks. I was trying to optimize the code, by using hash and looping through to run the tests, so started using angularjs.forEach(). But, it appears that, the angular.constant is not visible inside the angular.forEach(). Any idea why constant is not accessible (while service is) inside angular.forEach()?

```
describe("utilsService:", function(){

    beforeEach(module('utilsService'));

    var KiB;
    var GiB;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_KiB_){
          KiB = _KiB_;
    }));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_GiB_){
          GiB = _GiB_;
    }));

    var utilsService;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_utilsService_){
          utilsService = _utilsService_;
    }));


    describe('Constant values', function() {

/* The below test works fine */
        it("KiB constant in describe", function(){
            console.log("KiB value is " + KiB);
            expect(KiB).toEqual(1024);
        });

        tests = {
          'KiB value': {
            'INPUTS': {
              'CONSTANT': KiB
            },
            'EXPECTED': {
              'VALUE': 1024
            }
          },
          'GiB value': {
            'INPUTS': {
              'CONSTANT': GiB
            },
            'EXPECTED': {
              'VALUE': 1024 * 1024
            }
          }
        }

        angular.forEach(tests, function(t_hash, t_name){

          var val = t_hash.INPUTS.CONSTANT;
          var exp_val = t_hash.EXPECTED.VALUE;

/* The below test is failing */
          it(t_name, function(){
              console.log("TC: " + test_api_name + " " + t_name );
              expect(val).toEqual(exp_val);
          })
        });

    });
```

Note: Call to Service functions (like below compareSize()) is working just fine.

```
describe('compareSize()', function() {
    test_api_name = 'compareSize()';
    tests = {
      'size1 is greater than size2': {
        'INPUTS': {
          'SIZE1_UNIT': '2 TB',
          'SIZE2_UNIT': '2048 KB'
        },
        'EXPECTED': {
          'RETURN': 1
        }
      },

      'float size1 is greater than int size2': {
        'INPUTS': {
          'SIZE1_UNIT': '1.50 TB',
          'SIZE2_UNIT': '1 TB'
        },
        'EXPECTED': {
          'RETURN': 1
        }
      }
    }

    angular.forEach(tests, function(t_hash, t_name){
      var size1_unit = t_hash.INPUTS.SIZE1_UNIT;
      var size2_unit = t_hash.INPUTS.SIZE2_UNIT;
      var exp_ret = t_hash.EXPECTED.RETURN;

      it(t_name, function(){
          console.log("TC: " + test_api_name + " " + t_name );
          var ret = utilsService.compareSize(size1_unit, size2_unit);
          expect(ret).toEqual(exp_ret);
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem (problem 1) is that *beforeEach()* is called before each **it()**,
so when you define "tests" you are "out" of an *it()* and KiB/Gib are undefined.

(you can verify the order of calls using console.log)
You can solve this by putting the instantiation of *tests* inside a beforeEach()

and putting the forEach loop into an it().

Example:

```
    var KiB;
    var GiB;
    var tests;   

    beforeEach(function(inject(_KiB_, _GiB_) ){

console.log("set Kib and Gib");
        KiB = _KiB_;
        GiB = _GiB_;

console.log("define tests");
        tests = tests || {
          'KiB value': {
            'INPUTS': {
              'CONSTANT': KiB
            },
            'EXPECTED': {
              'VALUE': 1024
            }
          },
          'GiB value': {
            'INPUTS': {
              'CONSTANT': GiB
            },
            'EXPECTED': {
              'VALUE': 1024 * 1024
            }
          }
        }              
    });
```

But I want to suggest you a different way to test your constants:

```
  describe("Constant values:", function(){        

       it("KiB value should be 1024", function(){
           expect(KiB).toEqual(1024);           
       });

       it("GiB value should be 1024*1024", function(){
           expect(GiB).toEqual(1024*1024);           
       });

    });
```

.. or more punctual:

```
describe("Constant: KiB", function(){
    var KiB;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_KiB_){
        KiB = _KiB_;
    }));
    it("its value should be 1024", function(){
        expect(KiB).toEqual(1024);
    });        
});  

describe("Constant: GiB", function(){
    var GiB;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_GiB_){
        GiB = _GiB_;
    }));
    it("its value should be 1024*1024", function(){
        expect(GiB).toEqual(1024*1024);
    });        
});
```

Honestly, I think these are the right tests to do, but, in any case if/when the "problem 1" (definition of KiB/GiB out of an it()) will be solved this is the way I would do the job:

```
describe("Constants are well defined", function(){
       [
           { name: "KiB value should be 1024", value: KiB, expectedValue: 1024 }, 
           { name: "GiB value should be 1024*1024", value: GiB, expectedValue: 1024*1024 }
       ]
       .forEach(function(test){
           it(test.name, function(){
               expect(test.value).toEqual(test.expectedValue);                
           })
       });  
   });
```

Alessandro